# Object Oriented Design Associations

Tags: uml

I've been doing this practice exam and I can't seem to get the answer to this question. I feel like the one to one and the many to one would both be 2. This obviously is wrong, but I can't think through it. Any ideas or answers would be appreciated. If I could see the right answer then I can at least try to figure out why that's right.

Match the relationship cardinality and its implied navigability with the best refinement process:

---

Many-to-many

---

Many-to-one

---

One-to-many

---

One-to-one

1. Add a single attribute of the target type to the many side of the relationship.
2. Add a single attribute of the target type to the one side of the relationship.
3. Add a collection attribute to the many side of the relationship.
4. Add a collection attribute to the one side of the relationship.

Comment: One parent - many children. One spouse - one partner. Many clubs - many members. Why should they all be 2?

Comment: Given the four sentences, if you replace the word _single_ with _one_ and the word _collection_ with _many_, the sentences would seem to resolve directly into the four cardinality choices.

Comment: Awesome.  I was confused as to what side of the relationship the attribute was being added. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at it from an Object Oriented perspective, the sentence make perfect sense. Imagine two classes, now simply go over each of the statements:

> Add a single attribute of the target type to the many side of the relationship.

Here you have a relation of one to many. If you add a single attribute to the target of the many side of the relation, then all of those class instances can only refer to one single class as the attribute can only hold one value. The answer is One-to-Many. An example would be the relationship between a car and its tires. A car can reference many (usually 4+1) tires but each tire only references the car it belongs to.

> Add a single attribute of the target type to the one side of the relationship.

Similar to the argument above, here each instance can only reference one other instance. Say how a car references its steering column and vice-versa.

> Add a collection attribute to the many side of the relationship.

A collection attribute can hold many values. In this case, multiple instances of one class can reference multiple instances of the other class. This many-to-many type relationship can be modelled by the relation of a club to its members. Usually a club has many members and each of these members can be in many clubs.

> Add a collection attribute to the one side of the relationship.

Here you have a Many-to-One relationship with many instances of one class being able to reference only one single instance of a target class. An example is the inverse relationship of a car to its tires as I gave above.

Note that Many-to-One and One-to-Many are inverse relationships and whether you call it the first or the latter depends on the semantics you are using.

A final tip, if you are thinking about Object Oriented Design, it helps to use analogies of your daily life and abstract them to comprehend the intricacies of many object-oriented models and meta-models.

Comment: I think the One to many and many to one should be reversed in your response. For example if you have a class of car and the navigability is directed towards a class of tires with a 'many' multiplicity. We will be adding  a collection attribute to the one side of the relationship. The Car class will have a collection tires. I believe when the author says one-to-many that navigability is from left to right. The attribute is added to the the source of the navigation.